# syslog() calls failing to log anything in PHP

Tags: php, syslog

I have some PHP code that's calling syslog(). I have control over the server. No matter what combination of openlog(), closelog(), priority and facility I try it will not log to the syslog. Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: Not without showing us what it is you're doing.

Comment: Are you sure syslog is running on the system you writing to?

Comment: How do you know nothing is in the syslog?

Comment: When I output to the syslog from the command-line, like 'logger asdf', I see asdf in the log. My syslog.conf file is ok -- but PHP can't write to the syslog.

Comment: does the php script work on command line? your web server probably runs as a different user which might not be able to use the syslog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to mount the /dev/log device in the chroot jail that PHP was running under.